# How to avoid anaphoric macro in Clojure?

Tags: macros, clojure

Take this (simplified) example:

```
(defmacro make [v & body]
  `(let [~'nv ~(some-calc v)]
     ~(map #(if (= % :value) 'nv %) body)))
```

Right now the symbol `nv` is hardcoded. Is there a way to somehow gensym `nv` and still being able to use it in the map function?

By the way, is this actually an anaphoric macro?

Comment: Not sure if you can call it anaphoric: to be so, `nv` should refer to some portion of the macro invocation form. If you factor out `some-calc` from the macro body then you'll have a more proper anaphoric invocation: `(make (some-calc x) (do-something-to nv))` where `nv` refers to `(some-calc x)`. In your case you'll have `(make x (do-some-thing-to nv))`, but then `nv` would not directly refer to anything in the macro invocation form.

Comment: @skuro: I see, so basically this is the worst of both worlds - introducing a new symbol which however is going to remain hidden until somebody accidentally redefines it. Hf tracking that bug down :) Fortunately, an explicit `gensym` as per amalloy's suggestion solves this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is contained within the question: just use `gensym` like you would if Clojure didn't have auto-gensyms.

```
(defmacro make [v & body]
  (let [value-sym (gensym)]
    `(let [~value-sym ~(some-calc v)]
       ~@(replace {:value value-sym} body))))
```

Note that I'm not sure whether you really want `~` or `~@` here - it depends if `body` is supposed to be a sequence of expressions to execute in the `let`, or a sequence of arguments to a single function call. But `~@` would be a lot more intuitive/normal, so that's what I'm going to guess.

Whether this macro is anaphoric is a little questionable: definitely introducing `nv` into the calling scope was, but it was basically unintentional so I would say no. In my revised version, we're no longer introducing `nv` or anything like it, but we are "magically" replacing `:value` with `v`. We only do that at the topmost level of the body, though, so it's not like introducing a real scope - I'd say it's more like making the client's code unexpectedly break in corner cases.

For an example of how this deceptive behavior can crop up, imagine that one of the elements of `body` is `(inc :value)`. It won't get replaced by the macro, and will expand to `(inc :value)`, which never succeeds. So instead I'd recommend a *real* anaphoric macro, which introduces a real scope for a symbol. Something like

```
(defmacro make [v & body]
  `(let [~'the-value ~(some-calc v)]
     ~@body))
```

And then the caller can just use `the-value` in their code, and it behaves just like a real, regular local binding: your macro introduces it by magic, but it doesn't have any other special tricks.

Answer (score 3):

It's not actually an anaphoric macro as I understand it.

An anaphoric equivalent would have give you a syntax like:

```
(make foo 1 2 3 4 it 6 7 it 8 9)
```

i.e. the symbol `it` has been defined so that it can be used inside the body of the make macro.

I'm not sure precisely if this is what you want because I don't have enough context on how this macro is going to be used, but you could implement the above like:

```
(defmacro make [v & body]
   `(let [~'it ~v]
      (list ~@body)))

(make (* 10 10) 1 2 3 4 it 6 7 it 8 9)
=> (1 2 3 4 100 6 7 100 8 9)
```

Alternatively, if you're not really trying to create new syntax and just want to replace `:value` in some collection, then you don't really need a macro: it would be better to just use [replace](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/replace):

```
(replace {:value (* 10 10)} [1 2 :value 3 4])
=> [1 2 100 3 4]
```

Comment: Even though I'm accepting amalloy's answer this was very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your example, both `some-calc` and `map` happen during macroexpansion, not at runtime, thus `nv` does not need to be `let` anyway. The macro itself is not written properly, irrespective of anything to do with symbol capture.

Comment: As I said, this is a simplified example; the macro actually returns a `fn` that is going to be called relatively often, hence the "caching" in the let.

Comment: I don't really buy this, Alex - it's pretty clear that his `map` is intended to happen during macroexpansion, and it's entirely plausible that `some-calc` could be as well. For example, perhaps `(some-calc 'x)` returns `'(inc (doto x prn))` - perfectly suitable for use in that context, and needs to be `let` to avoid repeating the side effect of printing.

Comment: Certainly calling `map` and `some-calc` during expansion might be correct.  My point was that the `let` of `nv` doesn't actually do anything, thus the macro itself didn't make any sense with respect to the question about `nv`.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use a dynamic binding.

```
(declare ^:dynamic *nv*)

(defmacro make [v & body]
  `(binding [*nv* ~(some-calc v)]
     ~(map #(if (= % :value) *nv* %) body)))
```

In practice, dynamic variables suck when their scope is too wide (it's harder to test and debug programs etc.), but in cases like this where the scope is confined to the local calling context where an anaphor is needed, they can be quite handy.

An interesting aspect of this use is that it's kind of the inverse of a common idiom of using a macro to hide a dynamic binding (many in the with-* style).  In this idiom (which as far as I know is not all that common) the binding is used to expose something hidden by the macro.

Comment: Yea, I recently started (ab)using dynamic bindings and am still exploring cases where they could be useful. Thanks for the idea!